# Orbital insertion accuracy for SpaceX payloads

Tags: spacex, launch, payload, payload-deployment, accuracy

What is the orbital insertion accuracy of SpaceX for positioning its payload (for example satellites)? How close do they get to the requested or target orbital parameters?

I tried to research this on the internet, but I could only find post discussing the precision of landing the reusable boosters, not for the payload.

Answer (score 7):

The [Falcon User manual](https://www.spaceflightnow.com/falcon9/001/f9guide.pdf) provides some information:

> 4.5. Mission Accuracy Data As a liquid propellant vehicle with restart capability, Falcon 9 provides the flexibility required for payload
> insertion into orbit with higher eccentricity and for deploying
> multiple payloads into slightly different orbits. Until verified by
> actual operations, SpaceX expects to achieve the following minimum
> target orbital insertion accuracy:
>
> Low Earth Orbit
>
> • Perigee ±10 km
>
> • Apogee ±10 km
>
> • Inclination ±0.1 deg
>
> • Right Ascension of Ascending Node ±0.15 deg
>
> Geosynchronous Transfer Orbit
>
> • Perigee ±10 km
>
> • Apogee ±10 km
>
> • Inclination ±0.1 deg
>
> • Right Ascension of Ascending Node ±0.75 deg
>
> • Argument of Perigee ±0.3 deg